# React antd table expandedRowRender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, antd

I'm in need of some help.

I have a datasource on my antd table in my React.Component. On that table i've set the attribute expandedRowRender:

```
  <Table
    bordered
    size="small"
    columns={columns}
    rowKey={record => record.id}
    expandedRowRender={record => (
      <ProductDetailView
        record={record}
        onChange={this.OnCoverageProductNumberChanged()}
      />
    )}
    dataSource={products}
    pagination={this.state.pagination}
    loading={this.props.isProductsLoading}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
  />
```

which is currently sending a record to ProductDetailView which is a react.component. I would like to know how I can send the row index to the onChange event as well, so I can track on which row I am looking at.

I hope this is enough information, basically I just need to know how to send the row index to my onChange event.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You want to send row index to the onChange for `ProductDetailView` component or for `Table` component?

Comment: the tables row index which productdetailview is created on. That would be nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second variable of

```
expandedRowRender={(record, i) => <p>{i}</p>}
```

is the row index

you can pass it like this

```
expandedRowRender={(record, i) => 
    <ProductDetailView 
        record={record} 
        onChange={() => this.OnCoverageProductNumberChanged(i)}
    />
}
```

Comment: Ahh you are a lifesaver. I'm currently new to the whole lambda expressions and react / javascript. I will accept as soon as stackoverflow allows me too

Comment: Your welcome, usually loop function in React will set the second variable as index, I've checked the document from [antd] it does not show clearly but when I tried on the code level it shows that's correct.